# Data is displaying successfully by passing invalid URL(adding backslash in URL)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am getting successfully JSON response even if I add extra backslash() in URL as like below:

```
https://localhost:8080//////\/\\\\\/rest//v1///kems///stats?btv=doerrja
```

JSON Response:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "636803914206857000",
        "Rank": "2.401",
        "Artifact_State": "In Arbeit",
        "Count": "10"
    },
    {
        "ID": "636803920812123000",
        "Rank": "1.372",
        "Artifact_State": "Keine Änderung möglich",
        "Count": "1"
    }
]
```

How to handle this case in Java?

Comment: the case in which there's no error? : S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally below solution worked for me:

**pom.xml:**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.Application;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    /* 
     * Method allow to access any resource without any authentication
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

**UrlFilter.java**

```
package com.component;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.daimler.datalayer.apistreamintegration.exception.BadRequest;

@Component
public class UrlFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UrlFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterChain) throws ServletException {

    }


    /* 
     * filter call to check if any double forward slash(//) present in URI before invoking Controller class 
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        LOGGER.info("Filtering the url");
        if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            return;
        }
        String requestURI = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
        boolean isInvalidUrl = requestURI.contains("//");
        if (isInvalidUrl) {
            throw new BadRequest("The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

**BadRequest.java**

```
package com.exception;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequest extends RuntimeException {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


  public BadRequest(String message) {
    super(message);
  }


  public BadRequest(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[snapshot of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vowoT.png)

from what I can see I think it is consuming one '/' at once and treating the rest as a parameter and then again recursively treating each '/' as a separate path eventually reaching to the actually sensible values that you've tried to pass

Comment: My question is why I am getting successfully response even I add backslash (\),  what is the reason behind it, is this general behavior?  Also seeing if adding multiple farward slash (/) I am getting successful response. What is reason behind it?

Comment: From the Spring Doc i found there is one class name StrictHttpFirewall which is having methods as below which can be helpful to implement the same, but I don't know how to use it: setAllowBackSlash(boolean allowBackSlash)
Determines if a backslash "\" or a URL encoded backslash "%5C" should be allowed in the path or not and setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(boolean allowUrlEncodedSlash)
Determines if a slash "/" that is URL encoded "%2F" should be allowed in the path or not. I want to throw exception if anyone is giving extra backslash or forward slash in URL. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Spring Doc URL link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/StrictHttpFirewall.html